# how to send multiple selected values of dropdown to list ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a dropdown list where user can select multiple values(TurbineID). I have to send this multiple values (TurbineID) by using Ajax or Json. How can I do that? I have attached my code (snippet) here.

```html
<td><b>select a Turbines</b></td>
<td style="text-align: right;cursor: pointer" ><img src="../images/SelecAll.gif" alt="all turbines" onclick='getAllTurbines()'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
  <select id="selectTurbineByID" onchange="getSelectedTurbine();" style="width: 100%;" size="8" multiple="multiple" class="optbox"></select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to get all selected option in list and then json that list

```
  function SelectedValues(){
    var result=[] 
    $("#selectTurbineByIDoption:selected").each(function(){
                    result.push($(this).val();
                });
    return result
    }
    function functionForSendingAjax(){
    var option=SelectedValues();
     jsondata=json.stringify({"data":option});
    ajax({
    data:jsondata;
    //url:
    //success:

    });
    }
```